# using a href to pass value for $_GET[] not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I was using GET on a webpage to handle applying filters to a MYSQL query which displayed items from a database, the information was then displayed in a div and at the bottom of the div I had this.

```
<a href="tyreDetails.php?id=<?php echo $product["recid"]; ?>">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-primary">Details</button>
</a>
```

This was then used on another page. To display the information again using the id of the item.

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $id = mysqli_escape_string($db, $_GET['id']);

    $featuredSql = "SELECT t.*, s.quantity, s.rrp AS nRetailPrice, r.city AS city_name, ts.thumbnail as tread_thumbnail, ts.bigpic as tread_bigpic, t.rating FROM tyres t INNER JOIN stocklevels s 

ON t.stockcode=s.stockcode LEFT JOIN tyre_treads ts ON t.treadid=ts.recid LEFT JOIN reseller r ON s.city=r.recid WHERE s.quantity>0 AND s.rrp>0 ";

    // $featuredResult = mysqli_query($db, $featuredSql);

    if ($id != 'Any' && $id != null) $featuredSql .= " AND t.recid='$id' LIMIT 1";

    if (!$featured = mysqli_query($db, $featuredSql)) die(mysqli_error());
    var_dump($featured);
    if (!$tyre1 = mysqli_fetch_object($featured)) echo "<br />No tyres match those parameters. Please try again.";

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($featured, MYSQLI_NUM);

    $read = $row[1];
}
```

I changed a form on the first page from using GET to using POST, now I get a 500 error from the server. The url looks like website.com/tyreDetails.php?id=4243, so the value is being passed across.

I'm not sure why this no longer works? It worked fine until I changed the original search area to post, but this  is separated and isn't attached to a form at all.

EDIT**
I just reverted all the changes of the other form to post and it is still no longer working. I now assume that is not the problem.

Comment: you said you made it post type ? where is the code? i din't see post type code

Comment: Did you try error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: The post stuff was on another form on the page, but this <a href> is separate, the details page stopped working after I mage the changes. The post is used to get the information to display the product initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="tyreDetails.php?id=<?php echo $product["recid"]; ?>">
```

is a hyperlink so it wont be of "POST" type anyways.